# Boot into non-graphical mode from Grub prompt RHEL/CentOS 7

Tags: centos, rhel, grub

I know you can boot into single user mode by editing the kernel boot options at the grub prompt (by pressing "e" to edit) if you add the word "single," but how can you boot into non-graphical mode, what used to be called `init 3`? On Ubuntu, you can add the word "text" but that doesn't seem to work on CentOS 7.

Answer (score 11):

CentOS 7 uses systemd, and so uses *targets*.

If you permanently want a text-only mode (eg a server where you don't care about graphics) then you can tell systemd about this:

```
systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

Now on the next reboot you'll get a text console.  This is the same as the older `id:3:initdefault:` in `/etc/inittab` to set the default run level.

If you want a one-off reboot from grub (eg because of a bad video driver you're trying to fix) then the option to add to the `kernel` line is

```
systemd.unit=multi-user.target
```

Comment: The first option re `systemctl set-default multi-user.target` worked for me, however appending `systemd.unit=multi-user.target` in GRUB just continued to boot the graphical interface.

Comment: @Alxs : that was my experience as well, which is why I have been neglecting to accept this answer. However, I haven't been able to find any "official" docs, but sticking users with having to type `systemd.unit` et c. et c. at a console seems a more cruel than what Red Hat engineers typically put us through.

Comment: @Dmitri, please see my answer below.  It will resolve your issue.

Comment: `rd.systemd.unit=multi-user.target`  (or `rd.systemd.unit=graphical.target` if you have the alternate problem.)

Answer (score 5):

After pressing "e" to edit the GRUB menu, locate the line beginning with "linux16..." or "linuxefi..." and append " 3" to the end of that line.

You can get a good idea what else is in that line before you reboot by typing:

```
$  cat /proc/cmdline
```

For example, the output in my case is:

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64 root=UUID=2cc29b16-fe2b-400f-a39f-3e9048784599 ro vconsole.keymap=us crashkernel=auto vconsole.font=latarcyrheb-sun16 rd.driver.blacklist=radeon LANG=en_US.UTF-8 3
```

You can see the " 3" appended.

Answer (score 1):

When you type the code below at console:

```
cat etc/inittab
```

you will see this:

```
# inittab is no longer used when using systemd.
#
# ADDING CONFIGURATION HERE WILL HAVE NO EFFECT ON YOUR SYSTEM.
#
# Ctrl-Alt-Delete is handled by /usr/lib/systemd/system/ctrl-alt-del.target
#
# systemd uses 'targets' instead of runlevels. By default, there are two main targets:
#
# multi-user.target: analogous to runlevel 3
# graphical.target: analogous to runlevel 5
#
# To view current default target, run:
# systemctl get-default
#
# To set a default target, run:
# systemctl set-default TARGET.target
#
```

This tells that how to change the default runlevel.

Answer (score 0):

While `3` will work as a backwards compatibility (and easier to remember) method to get to text-only mode, the "correct" way to do it is to append `rd.systemd.unit=multi-user.target`  Note that this is different than what @stephen-harris mentioned above (missing the `rd.` which is required in for the initrd).  This is useful in case you are testing customer systemd targets and you want to boot to one that isn't covered by the compatibility options.  See here for the documentation:  https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.html#Kernel%20Command%20Line